# Aggregating 25 lists into one main list

Tags: list, aggregation

I've been asked to create 25 lists and sub-sites for each department in my organization and then roll all those 25 lists into 1 master list.

I'm currently using SharePoint 2010 Standard. I don't have server access. The lists use lookups and I tried creating a template of the first list and recreating in a subsite but got an error about broken columns and all my lookups broke in the form.

Is this a bad idea or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a content type which has all the fields in the list.

Now create list for each subsite and choose the content type as the default one.

For rolling up data use Content Query Webpart and choose the content type from the Webpart properties.

Comment: thanks for the reply. That's a good idea but do you know if it's possible to style the results like a grouped list view where I can expand/collapse by groupings? Something like this http://i.imgur.com/Y46Ldcn.png

Comment: It supports custom item styles using XSLT. Never tried it though.